# Extract value from xml in shell

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing

I have to following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOC SYSTEM "ts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="ts.css"?>
<DOC LOCALE="en-US"> 
   <PTXT ID="some.first.id" CONTEXT="">Some text 1</PTXT> 
   <PTXT ID="some.second.id" CONTEXT="">Some text 2</PTXT> 
</DOC>
```

Now my challenge is to loop on every PTXT tag and do something with the ID and the inner text. For example purposes, let's just say that I need to echo something like

```
some.first.id Some text 1
some.second.id Some text 2
```

How can I have that in a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete solution with [**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//PTXT" -v "concat(./@ID,' ',text())" -n input.xml 2>/dev/null
```

The output:

```
some.first.id Some text 1
some.second.id Some text 2
```

Comment: Is there a way to not use tools that might not be installed on the machine?

Comment: @Robert, the right way is to use the RIGHT tools and not to invent wrong workarounds

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to give the sh file to someone who does not have xmlstarlet installed?

Comment: @Robert, All people should understand one simple thing: XML/HTML and JSON are standalone formats that should be parsed/processed with appropriate tools/parsers. All tricky workarounds with regex and others can NOT ever be called as robust, stable and flexible solutions

Comment: Ok, well I installed xmlStarlet and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: I have one more question, if you can help. Some of my values (ex. Some text 1) are formatted like "Some <NTI>text 1</NTI>" and your command extracts just "Some". How can I modify to take text 1 aswell?

Comment: @Robert, just change the xpath expression to `"concat(./@ID,' ', .)"`

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a life saver :)