# Update .properties file with values from .xml file

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

The following xmlstarlet command:

```
./xmlstarlet-1.5.0/xml.exe fo --dropdtd $filename | ./xmlstarlet-1.5.0/xml.exe sel -t -m "//DOC//PTXT" -v "concat(./@ID,' ', .)"
```

returns multiple results, because my file contains a lot of `doc/ptxt`. I need to do something with each output, more explicitly I need to do something with each ptxt value. How can I loop through all results of `XMLstarlet`?

My output looks something like:

```
my.id.one Text I need 
my.id.two Text I also need
my.id.three Surprisingly I need this text too
```

and what I need is to have each `id-text` pair in maybe two variables `id` and `text`, because I have another file containing `id-value` pairs and I need to match those pairs.

**Update 1:**

A concrete example of what I need to do:
I have file `X.xml` and file `Y.properties`
File `X.xml` has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOC SYSTEM "ts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="ts.css"?>
<DOC LOCALE="en-US"> 
    <PTXT ID="text.something">Open door</PTXT> 
    <PTXT ID="text.something.else">Open another door</PTXT>
    <PTXT ID="text.whatever">Close all</PTXT>
</DOC>
```

File `Y.properties` has the following structure:

```
text.something=Open window
text.something.else=Open another door
```

The result that I expect is `Y.properties` with this content:

```
text.something=Open door
text.something.else=Open another door
text.whatever=Close all
```

To do:

- If `value` from `id` in `X.xml` is different than `value` from `key` in `Y.properties`, the `value` from `key` in `Y.properties` should be updated.
- If `value` from `id` in `X.xml` is the same as `value` from `key` in `Y.properties`, nothing should be done
- If `id` from `X.xml` is not present as `key` in `Y.properties`, it should be added with its `value` from `X.xml` to `Y.properties`

My current shell code is:

```
for filename in C:/Temp/XLocation/*.xml; do
        ./xmlstarlet-1.5.0/xml.exe fo --dropdtd $filename | ./xmlstarlet-1.5.0/xml.exe sel -t -m "//DOC//PTXT" -v "concat(./@ID,' ', .)"
done
```

which currently only takes every id/value from X.xml and prints to std output.
The `for` is there, as you probably suspect, because I have multiple `X.xml` and `Y.properties` on which I must execute this code.

**Problem 1:**
@janos I have the following problem and I really don't understand why. It all works ok, but few of them don't. Example: 
X.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOC SYSTEM "ts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="ts.css"?>
<DOC> 
<PTXT ID="a.b.c.d" CONTEXT="label"><NTI>Text</NTI></PTXT>
</DOC>
```

Y.properties:

```
a.b.c.d=Text
```

and my output is:

```
a.b.c.d=
    Text=
=
```

Can you please help me as I really don't understand what's going on.

**Problem 2:**
Having the following input:
X.xml

```
my.id = \u00D6ffnen Express WebTools
```

and Y.properties

```
<PTXT ID="my.id" CONTEXT="">Öffnen <NTI>Express WebTools</NTI></PTXT>
```

results in:
out.properties

```
my.id=Öffnen Express WebTools
my.id=\u00D6ffnen Express WebTools
```

instead of

```
my.id=Öffnen Express WebTools
```

Comment: Please show some sample input and your desired output: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is continuation of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393839/extract-value-from-xml-in-shell/47393943?noredirect=1#comment81775824_47393943. Elaborate how each outputted item should be processed

Comment: Well, each output gives me an ID an some text for that ID. I need to have each output as variable maybe to I can search that ID in another file and check if the text is correct or not (correct meaning the same).

Comment: Add your second file and the desired output to your question.

Comment: you wrote *I have multiple `X.xml` and `Y.properties`*. How one should know that some `Input1.xml` related to `??? <unknown ... name>.properties` ? Elaborate that relation

Comment: I have something like Input_1.xml that should be matched with Output_1.properties and so on. So in other words, both X and Y have the same ending in the name so I know how to match them.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.6
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First generate the data to match the format in `Y.properties`:

```
xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd a.xml | \
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//DOC//PTXT" -v $'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")'
```

For your example this produces:

```
text.something=Open door
text.something.else=Open another door
text.whatever=Close all
```

Then you can use Awk to perform the following logic:

- Use the output of the previous command as *the first file* with `-`
- Use `Y.properties` as *the second file*
- Process line by line, using `=` as a separator, and building up a map of key-value pairs, using a simple logic: if the key is not in the map, add the key-value pair.
  Since we will get the lines of the `xmlstarlet` output first,
  the above logic will add all those values to the mapping.
  As we process the lines of the second file (`Y.properties`),
  lines whose key is already in the map will be ignored,
  but new key-value pairs will be added.

Like this:

```
xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd a.xml | \
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//DOC//PTXT" -v $'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")' | \
  awk -F= '!($1 in m) { m[$1] = $2 }
           END { for (key in m) { print key "=" m[key] } }' - Y.properties
```

You can redirect the output to the desired target file.

To perform the above to multiple files,
you can wrap the above code in a function,
with appropriate parameters.
For example:

```
mergeprops() {
    local filename=$1
    local propsfile=$2
    local out=$3

    xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd "$filename" | \
      xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//DOC//PTXT" -v $'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")' | \
      awk -F= '!($1 in m) { m[$1] = $2 }
               END { for (key in m) { print key "=" m[key] } }' - "$propsfile" | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' > "$out"
}

for filename in /c/Temp/XLocation/*.xml; do
    mergeprops "$filename" Y.properties "$filename.out"
done
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I posted another question for the problems found, as your solution answers my initial question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511395/update-properties-file-with-values-from-xml-file-problems