# Update .properties file with values from .xml file - problems

Tags: xml, shell, properties, xmlstarlet

Following [Update .properties file with values from .xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411993/update-properties-file-with-values-from-xml-file) I have the following problems:

**Problem 1**: Example: X.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOC SYSTEM "ts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="ts.css"?>
<DOC> 
    <PTXT ID="a.b.c.d" CONTEXT="label"><NTI>Text</NTI></PTXT>
</DOC>
```

Y.properties:

```
a.b.c.d=Text
```

and my output is:

```
a.b.c.d=
    Text=
=
```

Can you please help me as I really don't understand what's going on.

**Problem 2**: Example: X.xml

```
my.id = \u00D6ffnen Express WebTools
```

and Y.properties

```
<PTXT ID="my.id" CONTEXT="">Öffnen <NTI>Express WebTools</NTI></PTXT>
```

results in: out.properties

```
my.id=Öffnen Express WebTools
my.id=\u00D6ffnen Express WebTools
```

instead of

```
my.id=Öffnen Express WebTools
```

**Update**

- All my files contains nested NTI, no NTI and text with nested NTI combined.
- I cannot join string that ends with = as janos suggested because my output is something like:

  first.id=
  second.id=Text from second id
     Text from first id=
  I don't know what's wrong with stackoverflow but it seems that it's not seeing my code as code....

Comment: Add your xmlstarlet commands to your question.

Comment: My xmlstarlet command is the answer from the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example XML file, and this command:

```
xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd "$file" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/DOC/PTXT" -v $'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")'
```

I get this output:

```
a.b.c.d=
    Text
```

In the `concat` of the `xmlstarlet` if I change the `.` to `./NTI`, I get the output:

```
a.b.c.d=Text
```

So I see two options for you.
If some of your input files contain the `NTI` and other input files don't,
*and there are no input files with a mix of `NTI` present and absent*,
then you could add a conditional to detect whether the file contains the nested `NTI` or not, and use different `xmlstarlet` command accordingly.
For example:

```
if xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd "$file" | xmlstarlet el | grep -q DOC/PTXT/NTI; then
    cmd=$'concat(@ID, "=", ./NTI, "\n")'
else
    cmd=$'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")'
fi

xmlstarlet fo --dropdtd "$file" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/DOC/PTXT" -v "$cmd"
```

If a single XML file may contain both structures,
nested NTI and no nested NTI,
then another option is to use `$'concat(@ID, "=", ., "\n")'`,
but process the output, joining lines that end with `=` with the next line.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Unfortunately all my files contains nested NTI, no NTI and text + NTI.

Comment: That’s the thing. All my files contain nested NTI on some PTXT, some PTXT have no NTI at all and some PTXT have mixed text + nested NTI